# Cannot assign sorted array to a variable in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to sort one array and assign it to the other. Both arrays are identically defined like so:

```
var arrayA: [String: [Int]] = [:]
var sortedArrayA:[String: [Int]] = [:]

sortedArrayA = arrayA.sort{ $0.0 < $1.0 } // error on this line.
```

I am gettin this error:

> Cannot assign value of type [(String, [Int])] to type [String : [Int]]

What I'm trying to achieve is to make this dictionary:

```
["c" : [1,2,3], "a" : [2,3,3], "b" : [4,4,4]]
```

sorted like this:

```
["a" : [2,3,3], "b" : [4,4,4], "c" : [1,2,3]]
```

If it makes sence.

Comment: Neither `arrayA` nor `sortedArrayA` are arrays. They are dictionaries and dictionaries are unordered by definition.

Comment: Also there is no attempt to invoke any sorting method.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. So I can't sort a dictionary?

Comment: @HelloimDarius, you can sort dictionaries. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you say that you use array but actually you are using dictionaries. And your syntax for this is wrong. you can declare empty dictionary like this: `var dictionary: [String:Int] = ()`. But to answer your real question you can achieve it like this:

```
    let arrayA = ["c" : [1,2,3], "a" : [2,3,3], "b" : [4,4,4]]

let sortedDict = arrayA.sort { $0.0 < $1.0 }
print("\(sortedDict)")
```

Comment: Okay, I tried with let and everything seems ok. But when I try assigning it to a property (variable that could be used inside class scope) it gives me error.

Comment: You do not have to use let. What error do you get?

Comment: You'll get an error because this doesn't output a dictionary, it outputs an array of key-value pair tuples. Outputting a dictionary wouldn't make any sense here as, others have already said, they are unordered by definition.

Comment: @originaluser2 I agree. But how should I define my variable and get an error.

Comment: @HelloimDarius Depends on exactly what you're trying to achieve here – could you please edit your question with this information? If you just want a property of the same type, you'll want to annotate it as `[(key: String, value: [Int])]`.

Comment: @originaluser2 Yes ! That's exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I *know* closures in Swift are cool. But they are not cool enough to infer that you want to sort an array from this code:

```
var arrayA: [Int] = []
var sortedArrayA:[Int] = []

sortedArrayA = arrayA{ $0 < $1 }
```

And your code is even worse! You didn't even declare arrays! What you declared are dictionaries which are *supposed* to not be sorted!

Anyway, just learn the syntax of arrays: it's a pair of square brackets surrounding the type of array you want. So an array of `Int`s will be `[Int]` and an array of `String`s will be `[String]`.

Got it? Cool.

"But I only have dictionaries, though..." you said sadly. If you only have dictionaries, you can either sort its `keys` or `values`. I think you probably need to sort the values.

```
let values = someDictionary.values // if you want to sort keys, use .keys instead
```

Now you need to actually *call* the `sort` method in order to sort. Just writing a closure is *not* going to work.

```
let sortedValues = values.sort(<)
```

You can do this with any arrays of course!

```
let array = [3, 2, 1]
let sortedArray = array.sort(<)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and figure out the array sorting in `Playground`, in swift you can just use `.sort()` to sort the array. For example, for array of integers:

```
var array = [Int]() //initial empty array
array = [2, 1, 4, 3]
array = array.sort()  // array is now sorted
```